# Mean of ItoProcess

Tags: stochastic-calculus, random-process

I've defined the following ItoProcess

```
proc = ItoProcess[
  {
   \d bj[t] == bk[t] \d pj[t],
   \d bk[t] == bj[t] \d pj[t]
   },
  bk[t],
  {{bj, bk}, {bj0, bk0}},
  t,
  pj ~ GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[u, s, pj0]
  ]
```

proc evaluates to:

```
ItoProcess[{
  {u X[t], u X[t] bk[t], u X[t] bj[t]},
  {{s X[t]}, {s X[t] bk[t]}, {s X[t] bj[t]}},
  bk[t]}, 
  {{X, bj, bk}, {pj0, bj0, bk0}}, 
  {t,0}]
```

However `Mean[proc[t]]` or anything else I ask about `proc` returns unevaluated. I'm obviously doing something wrong. Is there a way to ask Mathematica for more insight about what the error could be?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this might not be supported, because I don't think there's anything really wrong with the input. If you substitute numeric values for `bj0` etc., you can generate samples with `RandomFunction`, so the syntax looks right to me.

Comment: Thanks @SjoerdSmit! It is very possible that this particular system of stochastic differential equations does not make sense (I'm still in the modelling phase).

Comment: One can express the geometric Brownian motion in terms of the more standard [WienerProcess](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WienerProcess.html?q=WienerProcess); can you make any progress, both in the modelling and in the code, using that ?